# gzip format streaming

Tags: c#, java, file, compression, gzip

Wondering if there's someone here with some experience with gzip format.  I have a very large gzip file that I need to parse.  However, I may only need a small portion of the decompressed text file.  Is is possible to stream this zip file without decompressing the entire file?

Anyone experience with gzip?

Comment: That depends. Arte its contents all separate files, or large files that you need to get portions from? I think that most gzip libraries out there (like lzma) have no problems with streaming individual files.

Comment: how would you determine what you need without decompressing the whole file?  or do you only need a portion starting at the beginning?

Comment: @Bartvbl - not sure i understand your comment.  the _gzip_ format is inherently a single stream format (which is why it is typically combined with tar, which can combine multiple files).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do realise that you can *stream* using standard java library classes right? It's quite trivial, something like:

```
GZIPInputStream stream = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream("some_file.gz"));
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(stream);

// Now read line by line... till you hit the content you want.
```

The entire file is not decompressed on the disk, just chunks as you need it in memory. And you can optionally re-compress and write back out again using the corresponding output streams.

Comment: didn't realize how easy it was!